# Sending raw TCP data from Linux to Windows server

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am planning to forward raw TCP data that is received on the local port of a Linux machine to a Windows server.

The forwarding is done by a Java application running on a Linux machine. A .NET application running on the Windows server receives this raw data and processes it.

I have read somewhere that the handling of LF and CR is different in Linux and Windows. Have someone encountered any problems in transferring raw TCP data between Linux and Windows?

Comment: What's "raw TCP data" here?  Are you generating some data and sending it, or are you going to have a service on your linux machine that receives some packets and forwards that data on to a Windows machine?  Either way, if you aren't processing the data on the linux part it shouldn't be changing line endings.  It's only something that's trying to interpret that data that would care about the line endings.  Anything that's just relaying it shouldn't even know if it's supposed to be ascii data or binary blobs

Answer (score 0):

You can send specially crafted packets with a tool like nping. In linux a newline \n will go to the next line, in windows newline and carriage return go to the next line \r\n

Comment: hping3 is a good tool as well

Answer (score -1):

This would only be an issue if the data was read and/or written on a line by line basis, which you wouldn't do when forwarding raw data. If it's simply forwarded on a packet per packet basis, no processing would be performed and the data would be exactly the same.

For the same reason, since data is read as bytes and not by a "text reader" or similar, neither line endings nor potential encoding (e.g. UTF-8) would make a difference.